# Get associated id for jQuery sortable connectWith serialize method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Using Rails 3.

Model in State table:

```
id
country_id
position
created_at
updated_at
```

Javascript:

```
$(".sortable_country").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable_country",
    update: function() {
        console.log($(this).sortable("serialize"));
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<strong>Country 1</strong>
<ul id="country_1" class="sortable_country">
    <li id="state_1">
        State 1
    </li>
    <li id="state_2">
        State 2
    </li>
    <li id="state_3">
        State 3
    </li>
    <li id="state_4">
        State 4
    </li>
</ul>
<strong>Country 2</strong>
<ul id="country_2" class="sortable_country">
    <li id="state_5">
        State 5
    </li>
    <li id="state_6">
        State 6
    </li>
    <li id="state_7">
        State 7
    </li>
    <li id="state_8">
        State 8
    </li>
</ul>
```

spots_controller.rb:

```
def sort
  params[:states].each_with_index do |id, index|
    State.update_all([&rsquo;position=?&rsquo;, index+1], [&rsquo;id=?&rsquo;, id])
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Please ignore other required code because I have streamlined the codes for troubleshooting purpose. In this example, I sort `State 5` to `Country 1` list. After sorting, the return serialize result is:

```
state[]=6&state[]=7&state[]=8
state[]=1&state[]=2&state[]=3&state[]=5&state[]=4
```

How can I include the associated `country_id` in the serialized result so that my app can appropriately update `State 5`'s `country_id` to `1`, which was initially `2` prior to sorting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this inside the `.sortable()`:

```
update: function() {
    $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
    .error(function() { 
    alert("Sorry, could not save the positions. Please refresh this page.");
    })
}
```

The associated IDs will automatically be posted in individual post after sorting.